# Is there any way to run all of or some of a py file and maintain the resulting state?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

If I have an IPython notebook and a separate py file, can I run all the code in that file and then have the resulting state in the notebook? Kind of like running `python -i myscript.py` from the command line where the `-i` flag then opens up an interpreter with the state after `myscript.py` has run. But instead, I'm in my existing notebook session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html):

```
%run script.py
```

It will run your script and all variables defined by the script will be in the global namespace of your `ipython` shell.

Using VSCode editor you can also run just part of your script file in a excecuting ipython shell with the shortcut <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

The `%load` magic is also nice, you copy the contents of the file to your working session, but it is better while running inside a notebook.

Comment: oh wow. I honestly thought there wouldn't be an answer for this one. will accept your answer as soon as the time buffer is up :)

Comment: while you're editing your answer, would you mind also adding in the "how" for running part of the script file. Indeed I am using VSCode

Comment: Sure! In doubt, just right click your selection.